# Solve the recurrence relation $x_{n} = \sqrt{1+\dfrac{3}{x_{n-1}}}$

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations

$x_{n} = \sqrt{1+\dfrac{3}{x_{n-1}}}$ with initial condition $x_1 = 2$.

Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}{x_n}$ exist.

I've calculated the first few values and it seems to be an oscillating series with tending towards $L$, where $L$ is the real root to the cubic $x^3 - x - 3 = 0$.

I've tried expressing the sequence as two monotone sub-sequences that converges to the same limit, but to no avail. Would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Prove by induction that:

$$x_{2n+2}<x_{2n}$$

$$x_{2n+1}>x_{2n-1}$$

---

$$x_{2n+2}=\sqrt{1+\frac3{\sqrt{1+\frac3{x_{2n}}}}}<\sqrt{1+\frac3{\sqrt{1+\frac3{x_{2n-2}}}}}=x_{2n}$$

$$x_{2n+1}=\sqrt{1+\frac3{\sqrt{1+\frac3{x_{2n-1}}}}}>\sqrt{1+\frac3{\sqrt{1+\frac3{x_{2n-3}}}}}=x_{2n-1}$$

Thus, it is monotone and each subsequence can likewise be shown to be bounded and therefore convergent.  Let $x^\star$ be the proposed limit.  Show by induction in the same manner as above that

$$\sqrt{\frac52}<x_{2n}<x^\star<x_{2n+1}<2$$

Answer (score 4):

To prove that the sequence defined by $x_1=2$ and $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{x_n}}$ is convergent you do not need to find an explicit form for $x_n$. As you noticed, if $x_n\to L$ then $L$ is a root of the polynomial $x^3-x-3$, that has a unique real root $\alpha\approx 1.6717$. So if such a sequence is convergent, it is convergent to $\alpha$. In order to prove it is convergent, you may apply the [Banach fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem). If $f(x)=\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{x}}$, we have $f'(x)=-\frac{3}{2 x^2 f(x)}$, hence $\left|f'(x)\right|\leq\frac{3}{4}<1$ for any $x\geq 1$ and $\alpha$ is an attractive fixed point.

Comment: "+1" for a slick argument.

Comment: @SahibaArora slick?  I'd just call it heavy duty.

Comment: I've accepted the other answer for now since I'm not familiar with Banach fixed point theorem and the other answer seems more tractable for me right now. I will read it up and try to understand what it is doing! Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Well then we have an example of a heavy duty slick argument.